# TypeError: this.oktaAuth.getUser is not a function .Unit test cases failing when using Okta library in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, authentication, testing, karma-jasmine

I am Using okta library for my authentication in angular8 .So far the functionalities are working fine but the project requirement is to write unit test cases in angular8. Below is my code for the service component and spec file.

I am creating one common service (AccessCheck service) where I am checking user access from okta library and returning the result to component. Using that result I am making api calls in my application. When I run the app functionality is working fine.

But when I run the basic setup of unit test in angular it fails at service call of okta and give error okta get user is not a function. I am not sure how to write test cases for third party library in angular. Any help will be appreciated

My Code

**Access-CheckService.ts**

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AccessCheckService {

constructor(private router: Router,

        private oktaAuth: OktaAuthService, private commonService: CommonService) { }
 
async checkUserAcess() {
        let userAccess = {
            adminFlag: false,
            isOnlyuserRole: false
        }
        await this.oktaAuth.getUser().then((user) => {
       localStorage.setItem("userAcces", JSON.stringify(userAccess))
        return userAccess
})

async checkAdGroupsandProjectIds() {
        let projectDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ProjectDetails'))
        let userRole = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userAcces'))
        if (!userRole) {
            userRole = await this.checkUserAcess()
        }
       let obj = {
            projectIds: projectDetails ,
            isOnlyuserRole: userRole 
        }
        return obj
    }
```

**JobDetials.component.ts**

```
export class JobDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private jobDetailsService: JobDetailsService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private commonService: CommonService,private router: Router,
    private accessCheck:AccessCheckService) { }

async ngOnInit() {   

    let userRoles = await this.accessCheck.checkAdGroupsandProjectIds()
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.details_id = params.get("id")    
    });


  if(!userRoles.isOnlyuserRole){
    this.getJobDetails(this.details_id,userRoles.projectIds,userRoles.isAdminFlag);
  }
}
```

**JobDetails.component.spec.ts**

```
describe('JobDetailsComponent', () => {

  let component: JobDetailsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<JobDetailsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [JobDetailsComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, MaterialModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule,MatSnackBarModule],

      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],

      providers: [{ provide: OktaAuthService, useValue: environment },AccessCheckService]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(JobDetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges()
  });

  it('should have job details component', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should have a title', () => {
    const compiled = fixture.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();                               /// failing here
    expect(compiled.querySelector('.title-container .title').textContent).toContain('Job Details:');
});
```

**enivironment.ts**

```
export const environment = {

  oktaIssuer: 'https://identity.mycompany.net',
  // oktaRedirectUrl: 'https://mycompany.net/signin',
  oktaRedirectUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/signin',
  oktaClientId: '1234Id',
  production: false
};
```

I am getting error like below for every test case written in spec file

```
TypeError: this.oktaAuth.getUser is not a function
TypeError: this.oktaAuth.getUser is not a function
    at AccessCheckService.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/services/accesscheck.service.ts:24:29)
```

If I change the providers array in spec file to

```
schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],

      providers: [OktaAuthService,AccessCheckService]
```

Then error changes to

```
your okta url is missing. you can copy your domain from the okta developer console
```

Comment: What's `environment` for `useValue`

Comment: Environment is issueurl, redirect url,callbac component.etc

Comment: `{ provide: OktaAuthService, useValue: environment }` means in place of OktaAuthService, you are using environment. You can't replace a class service by an object.

Comment: okay so what is the suggestion what should  i put in there?

Comment: .If i remove the use value part I get error ```your okta url is missing. you can copy your domain from the okta developer console```

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old but I thought I'd answer it for anyone looking this up in the future. The way to fix this problem is by adding OktaAuth as a provider and using a Jasmin spy to mock the get user call like so:

```
  {
      provide: OKTA_AUTH,
      useFactory: () => {
          const mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj('OktaAuth', ['getUser']);
          mockService.getUser.and.callFake(() => Promise.resolve({ name: 'Test' }));
          return mockService;
      }
  }
```

Just add that into your unit test providers array and you should be good to go.